# How to identify/authorize the sender of a message in a named pipe? (CreateNamedPipe)

Tags: winapi, named-pipes

I've created a communication between two applications using named pipes.
The first application creates a named pipe with `CreateNamedPipe` and reads the received messages with `ReadFile` sent by the second application. Both applications are able to communicate that way as intended.

Is it somehow possible to identify the sender of a received message?
Without some sort of identification (like getting the sender exe path) or authorization every other application could use that pipe to send messages to my application.

**(Edit)** Further details, because it seems it's important in this case:
The application that creates the pipe is running as a Windows service.
Both applications run locally on the same system.

Comment: You'd have to implement that yourself. Pipes are secured objects but the security model for Windows is not application oriented, it is user oriented.

Comment: Isn't there at least a way of finding out where the message is comming from? Something like a handle/name/path of the file that sent a message through the named pipe?

Comment: @CodeX not directly. The sender would have to identify itself inside the message data itself. The only thing the server can determine on its own is the user account that is running the app that sent the message. And to do that the server has to [impersonate the connected client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365573(v=vs.85).aspx) before it can then retrieve the user info. If the server has sufficient rights, it **might** be able to enumerate all open handles on the local system looking for any handles opened by that user and pointing to your server pipe name...

Comment: @CodeX ... but that is a very involved task, requiring low level APIs and knowledge of OS internals, and would only work for local processes anyway, not remote processes over the network.

Comment: [`ImpersonateNamedPipeClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378618(v=vs.85).aspx) exist. also exist **undocumented** `FSCTL_PIPE_QUERY_CLIENT_PROCESS` by using it we can got id of process who open named pipe

Comment: I've added some further details to the question. `ImpersonateNamedPipeClient` is new to me and might indeed be the starting point for a solution. I'm working with impersonation in another context already, but it's only regarding user privileges. I'm not sure about the best approach here in this case (enumerating all open handles or something different).

Comment: @RbMm: there's no need to use the control code, `GetNamedPipeClientProcessId` will do just as well. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston - yes, you right :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [GetNamedPipeClientProcessId()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365440(v=vs.85).aspx) will give you the process ID of the client process.  You can then open a handle to the process with [OpenProcess()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx) and call [GetModuleFileNameEx()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198(v=vs.85).aspx) to determine what application is running in that process.  You can then vet the application in whatever way you think best, e.g., you might want to check the identity of the [digital certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1130360/886887) or you might prefer to just check that the pathname is as you expect it to be.

Note that attempting to restrict access to a particular application rather than a particular user is never going to be robust; an attacker could always take control of the approved application and replace its code with their own.  Basically it isn't going to be more than a speed bump, but if you feel it is worth doing, it can be done.

---

If what you really want to know is what *user* has connected, you should instead be using [ImpersonateNamedPipeClient()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378618(v=vs.85).aspx) as already suggested in the comments, followed by [OpenThreadToken()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379296(v=vs.85).aspx) and so on.  Or better still, set the permissions when creating the named pipe so that only the authorized users are able to connect in the first place.

---

Now that you've clarified that the client runs with elevated privileges, I can make a more concrete recommendation: do both of the above.  **Configure the permissions on the named pipe** so that only members of the Administrators group can access it; that will ensure that only applications running with elevated privilege can access it.  Checking the executable as well won't hurt, but it isn't sufficient by itself, because an attacker could launch a copy of your application, suppress the requested elevatation, and inject their own code into the process.  (Or, as conio points out, modify their own process to make it look as if they are running your executable; GetModuleFileNameEx() is not intended to be used as a security measure, so it makes no effort to avoid spoofing.)

Comment: GetNamedPipeClientProcessId seems to be exactly what I'm looking for! I'm going to write some code tomorrow to test it. Regarding the security aspect: After finding out the application I'm going to check its signature with WinVerifyTrust(). That way I know my application hasn't been modified. If the attacker is able to overwrite the code in memory then there's definitely already a bigger problem on the system...

Comment: What's your threat model here?  The only reason to care about what *application* is connected rather than what *user* is connected is if you're trying to protect yourself *from the user*, which won't work because the user can always modify the code that is running in their own processes.

Comment: ... and the same applies to any malicious software running in the user's context, of course.

Comment: The threat is malware. I'd like to avoid the general possibility that some malware on the user's system sends messages/commands to my service. The basic idea is to only trust my own application. As long as the executable has not been modified I want to trust it.

Comment: Hmmm.  I'm doubtful that it will help much, because malware that isn't specifically aimed at attacking your service won't know how to send messages to it in the first place, and malware that *is* specifically aimed at attacking your service will know what application to masquerade as, and that's relatively easy to do.  But while your approach might not be much help, it probably won't do any harm either, so you may as well go ahead I guess.

Comment: I doubt that an attacker without elevated privileges will be able to masquerade as my digitally signed application in the restricted program files folder (that easily or at all). And in case he already acquired elevated privileges, he could do far worse things than targeting my service. If you still don't think that it's a safe approach, please provide some further details on a practical attack for this constellation, so can think it through with that additional information.

Comment: The attacker could launch your application, then (for example) inject a malicious DLL, in the same way shown in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31165487/886887).  Your code would be running, but so would his.  A more sophisticated approach would be to launch your application with the `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag and replace the code in-memory before letting the process start running; Cygwin does something like this to implement fork().  Neither of these attacks require elevated privileges, because the two processes are running in the same user context.  There are lots of other ways.

Comment: In this specific case my application is running with elevated privileges ("requireAdministrator") so this attack shouldn't be possible there. But I'll make sure to keep this in mind when it comes to other cases where the application runs with normal privileges. Thank you very much for your time, your valuable advice and of course for recommending GetNamedPipeClientProcessId, which I didn't find myself. I've just tested it. It works perfectly!

Comment: They could still run their own program, completely unrelated to yours, frankenstein the Ldr structures in the PEB, make the call to your program (write to the pipe), and then undo all the mess they did in the Ldr structures if they need to.

Comment: If the client is running with elevated privileges, you should definitely make sure that the security on the pipe is set so that only elevated processes (i.e., members of the Administrators group) can connect to it.  You can check the executable as well if you like, it won't do any harm.  But you may as well make use of the built-in security system, having two layers of protection won't hurt.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Actually it is insteresting discussion you all have here. Can you guide me if that possible some credential store/protected storage api/secure shared memory method that stored when the message is send from client, so the server can verify the it is from client rather that masquerade hacker's app? Assumed there is no possible for the masquerade to hook when my client is send the message, and they suppressed the my client message and send their. Assumed the app is write only using C# target .NET and know use some Win32 hook.

Comment: @Edward, assuming the server has admin privilege, I suppose it could use ReadProcessMemory and WriteProcessMemory to talk to the client process.  But I'm not sure what circumstances would allow the attacker to interfere with the client's pipe traffic but not with the client itself.